# How to use COLD START GPS feature in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, gps

I am creating a security app for portable devices, which uses GPS location to track devices and particular locations to encrypt/decrypt data. It is just the concept and continuing my research on that. For that i have to sometime cold start GPS. And i am newbie to windows app development, Is there a way that i can cold start the GPS from C# code using my app??

Comment: Is it for `Windows` or `WP`? Is it just to get the current location?

Comment: For the time windows phone, Not to get current location, Cold starting the GPS(means deleting all data which helps to fetch location).

Comment: "deleting all data" in the sense? If you could be more specific, would be great!

Comment: windows phone has some kind of flag SENSOR_PROPERTY_ CLEAR_ASSISTANCE_DATA which i don't know how to use?

Comment: You sure this supports for `WP`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn247372.aspx